# netbeans javadoc not refreshing

Tags: netbeans

I have one class and in Netbeans 7.0.1 I've inserted that class Javadoc

For example I have this:

```
/**
 * 
 * @return Returns cost of product
 */
public int getCustoTotal() {
    return this.custoTotal;
}
```

But if I do ALT+F1 i can see the html with javadoc but it's not the actual one. It's not reflecting latest changes.

Can you help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must explicitly regenerate the Javadoc for the changes to be reflected. The generation of Javadoc does not happen automatically as part of a standard build, and likewise does not happen on the per-file compilation that occurs on save, if you have that option checked.

To explicitly generate the Javadoc, right-click on the project and select 'Generate Javadoc', or choose the same entry from the 'Run' menu. Assign a keymap shortcut to it if you want quicker access to it.

You can probably add Javadoc generation to the standard build by customizing the Ant 'build.xml' file, but I doubt that that would affect the per-file on-save compilation. That is likely another section of the build file.